# Connect/Disconnect To Specific USB Device With One Button

Tags: usb

I have multiple speakers I connect to via USB and the one I use the most never shows on the "Previous" list no matter what I name it. So it's always multiple steps to connect.

Is there any app where I can create a single button to Connect/Disconnect To **Specific** USB Device?

Pixel 2XL

Comment: What steps do you perform for connecting the USB speakers?

Comment: Pull Down > Long press USB > Click on see all under Previously connected devices > long-press on the desired device